# Get real DPI in low api devices

Tags: android, dpi, android-screen

I use the following code to get the dpi in the x and y axis:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

try
{//API > = 17
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);

}catch(NoSuchMethodError e)
{//API < 17
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
}

float dpix = metrics.xdpi;
float dpiy = metrics.ydpi;
```

In API > = 17 devices I get real dpi of screen. Works well.

In API<17 devices, approximately 50% of cases (tested only with 6 physical devices) I get the proper value.

These are examples of failures of API< 17:

```
Samsung SGH-T599N: (xdpi+ydpi)/2 : 160.0 | Real device dpi: ~107 (ERR)    
Motorola DROID RAZR: (xdpi+ydpi)/2 : 366.5 | Real device dpi: ~256 (ERR) 
Samsung GT-S5570I : (xdpi+ydpi)/2 : 25.0 | Real device dpi: ~120 (ERR)   
Philips W536 : (xdpi+ydpi)/2 : 235.0 | Real device dpi: ~233 (OK)    
Acer    A1-830 : (xdpi+ydpi)/2 : 163.0 | Real device dpi: ~162 (OK)
```

How I can get the correct dpi API <17?